# String.Length strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net

I have example string with 5000+ chars. When I call `exampleString.Length`, I get (for example) 39764 chars. When I copy string into Notepad++, it shows 40523 chars.

Also, when I call `exampleString.Remove(5000)` and copy resulting string into Notepad++, it shows 5094 chars.

I guess that it is something with newline char, but can not figure out how to include newline char in Length?

---

### UPDATE

It is not Notepad++ related question.

I need to send string to service method which allows max 5000 chars. When I call `exampleString.Remove(5000)` and sent it to service, I got response error "only 5000 chars allowed"

Comment: Can you also check the ecoding in Notepad++? It could be a case of copying utf-8 strings into an Ansi mode.

Comment: Newline "char" could well be two characters (\r \n)

Comment: First try replicating the issue with smaller strings.  Find a string of length 10 in code that is length 5 or whatever when copied.  (You can likely just truncate a portion of the string you have.)  Then inspect the characters in question, that will likely indicate what's going on.

Comment: personally, I believe that the implementation of Strings is done better in the .Net Framework than in the Notepad++ Editor. So perhaps you post this question in the Notepad++ Help Board ...

Comment: You are copying string from debug view, aren't you? And string have all special characters encoded (like quotes, new line, tab,...)

Comment: @Servy: not true, see [String.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx).

Comment: Is the string UTF? ANSI? Unicode? Maybe the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w71hb4e(v=vs.90).aspx) can help out a bit?

Answer (score 2):

I guess Notepad++ shows you the size of the file, not the number of chars. And as soon as a lot of  encodings are using more then one byte per char - you have what you have.

Comment: Well, it shows both, depending on where you look.  He could be looking at the wrong place.

Comment: @Servy I can see the length (file length), but where I can see the number of chars?

Comment: No, Notepad++ shows num of chars. I know that because I send resulting string to service method with allows only 5000 chars, and I'm getting response error (more than 5000 chars)

Comment: @DaniloVulović if you mean the number after the 'length' word in the status bar, then you are wrong - this is a size of the file. Just play with different encodings and you will see.

Comment: @ie. I changed encoding and lenght is same

Comment: @DaniloVulović and after this change, are you sure that string looks exactly the same as before? ;)